# How to referece dictionary items cell address correctly

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

How do I copy a value from `WarehouseInventory` Sheet to `Scan Report` Sheet if that value exists on `dictionary items`?

I'm able to compare the values on both Sheets (columns) but having trouble referencing the dictionary items offset cell address.

---

*Example*

```
If List.Exists(Inv_Data(i, 1)) Then
    .Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 7).Value2 = "LPN SCANNED"
     SCAN_REPORT.Cells(x, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Inv_Data(i, 2)
Else
    .Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 7).Value = "LPN NOT SCAN"
End If
```

---

*`SCAN_REPORT.Cells(x, 1)` is adding the value on the last row*

---

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Example()
    Dim SCAN_REPORT As Worksheet
    Set SCAN_REPORT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scan Report")

    Dim List As New Scripting.Dictionary

    With SCAN_REPORT
        Dim Scn_LRow As Long
            Scn_LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim Scn_Data() As Variant
            Scn_Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Scn_LRow, 1)).Value2

        Dim x As Long
        For x = LBound(Scn_Data) To UBound(Scn_Data) Step 1
            DoEvents
            Debug.Print Scn_Data(x, 1)
            On Error Resume Next 'resume if dupe
            List.Add Scn_Data(x, 1), x
            On Error GoTo 0
            Debug.Print Scn_Data(x, 1), x
        Next

        Dim INVENTORY_REPORT As Worksheet
        Set INVENTORY_REPORT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WarehouseInventory")

        With INVENTORY_REPORT
            Dim Inv_LRow As Long
                Inv_LRow = INVENTORY_REPORT.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            Dim Inv_Data() As Variant
                Inv_Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Inv_LRow, 7)).Value2

            Dim i As Long
            For i = LBound(Inv_Data) To UBound(Inv_Data) Step 1
                DoEvents

                If List.Exists(Inv_Data(i, 1)) Then
                     .Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 7).Value2 = "LPN SCANNED"
                    SCAN_REPORT.Cells(x, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Inv_Data(i, 2)
'                    SCAN_REPORT.Cells(x, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value2 = Inv_Data(i, 3)
'                    SCAN_REPORT.Cells(x, 1).Offset(0, 3).Value2 = Inv_Data(i, 4)
                Else
                    .Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 7).Value = "LPN NOT SCAN"
                End If

            Next
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: With the code `List.Add Scn_Data(x, 1), x` do you want to keep the first x, the last x or does it matter at all?

Comment: The reason I ask is that there is a 'shorthand overwrite' method of `List(Scn_Data(x, 1)) =  x` where it adds the key/item if it doesn't exist but overwrites the item with the new x if it does exist. No error control necessary nor desired.

Comment: it does not matter at all, Thanks @Jeeped

Comment: When you `Inv_Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Inv_LRow, 7)).Value2` , Inv_Data  is a v2-D array, e.g. Inv_Data(1 to inv_lrow, 1 to 7) but your subsequent loop only increments the default first rank, e.g. `For i = LBound(Inv_Data) To UBound(Inv_Data) Step 1` is the same as `For i = 1 To Inv_LRow` so you never look outside of the first rank, e.g. `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Inv_LRow, 1))`. I don't see why you are collecting 7 columns of values into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a .CompareMode option and tightened up some code. HTHs.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Example()
    Dim SCAN_REPORT As Worksheet
    Set SCAN_REPORT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scan Report")

    Dim List As New Scripting.Dictionary
    List.comparemode = vbTextCompare      '<~~ ADDED!

    With SCAN_REPORT
        Dim Scn_LRow As Long
            Scn_LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim Scn_Data() As Variant
            Scn_Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Scn_LRow, 1)).Value2

        Dim x As Long
        For x = LBound(Scn_Data) To UBound(Scn_Data) Step 1
            'Debug.Print Scn_Data(x, 1)
            List.Item(Scn_Data(x, 1)) = x
            'Debug.Print Scn_Data(x, 1), x
        Next

        Dim INVENTORY_REPORT As Worksheet
        Set INVENTORY_REPORT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WarehouseInventory")

        With INVENTORY_REPORT
            Dim Inv_LRow As Long
                Inv_LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            Dim Inv_Data() As Variant
                Inv_Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Inv_LRow, 7)).Value2

            Dim i As Long
            For i = LBound(Inv_Data, 1) To UBound(Inv_Data, 1)
                'DoEvents

                If List.Exists(Inv_Data(i, 1)) Then
                    .Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 7).Value2 = "LPN SCANNED"
                    'i think this next line correction should resolve things
                    SCAN_REPORT.Cells(List.ITEM(Inv_Data(i, 1)), 1).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Inv_Data(i, 2)
                    'SCAN_REPORT.Cells(List.ITEM(Inv_Data(i, 1)), 1).Offset(0, 2).Value2 = Inv_Data(i, 3)
                    'SCAN_REPORT.Cells(List.ITEM(Inv_Data(i, 1)), 1).Offset(0, 3).Value2 = Inv_Data(i, 4)
                Else
                    .Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 7).Value = "LPN NOT SCAN"
                End If

            Next
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If there is a type mismatch on `List.ITEM(Inv_Data(i, 1))` just use a `CLng(...)` wrapper.

Comment: Thank for the confirm @L42, I'm trying to think ahead here as I'm lazy and unwilling to build a complete test workbook.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any use for `x` in your second loop. You need to retrieve the item (which is the row number you denoted as `x` when dumping values in the dictionary) associated with your *key*. Something like this might work:

```
SCAN_REPORT.Cells(List(Inv_Data(i, 1)), 1).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Inv_Data(i, 2)
```

However, this will only mark or update the last occurrence of data in `SCAN_REPORT` if you go with what Jeeped suggested in his comment(the shortcut in item overwriting). In your current code though, you will only update the first occurrence.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but @0m3r wasn't using the x, he was writing back from the the Inv_Data 2-D array if a dictionary match was found in the first rank.

Comment: @Jeeped I was re-reading his post too. But seeing the code, `x` will have its last value after the `For` statement  + 1 . And so the value will be written at the next empty row if that is the case at `SCAN_REPORT` sheet.

Comment: Yeah, I sometimes throw trash into the Item just so it doesn't throw an error when I only want a unique list of keys. I suspect @0m3r may be doing the same.

Comment: @Jeeped Ah I get it now, he just needs to add this line `x = x + 1` in his 2nd loop.

Comment: Ah ... I may have it better. How about `SCAN_REPORT.Cells(List.ITEM(Inv_Data(i, 1)), 1).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Inv_Data(i, 2)`

Comment: @Jeeped Haha I actually followed what you wrote in the comments and skipped the `Item` method and did the shortcut. But see my edit, maybe that is what he really want done. I'll wait for Om3r to come back. I may be wrong with my assumptions too.

Comment: I added my latest insight to my post. tbh, I'd much rather write dictionary code from scratch.

Comment: The edit example is not going work as `x` is the last row count, but the first example looks what I'm trying to do- Thank you @L42

Comment: @0m3r Thanks for confirmation. I deleted the edit :)

Comment: @0m3r - It seems that if you contribute to the SO community. you get the SO community's help in any way possible. Thanks L42.